# How can I access Indicator data?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

I wish to access data from an indicator in pine script. In mt4 I can use the function to do this. is there a similar function call in pine script "iCustom".

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a direct equivalent. There are four ways you might accomplish it though.

1. There exists some built in functions for common indicators that can be referenced under the `ta.` namespace such as `ta.rsi()`
2. Obtaining a series from another indicator applied to the chart. Your script must use only one `input.source()` and then it can use one output from another indicator that is applied to the chart as a source series which you can use in your script's calculation. It has to be set manually once both indicators are on your chart by changing your script's `input.source()` option to use the other indicator's output.
3. Create or use a library which performs the desired calculations and reference that from your script.
4. Directly include the code to perform the other indicator's calculation in your script.

Comment: With TV's [May 3 PineScript update](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/more-external-inputs-for-scripts-38014) people can use multiple `input.source()` calls.